Planning to rebuild detached storage room (in the US)
I have a detached storage room that is old and worn (leaks rain and has a smell of rat droppings) that I have a plan to tear down and rebuild in the near future. I'm looking for an architect and a general contractor (not sure if I need more).
What types of contractors should I be hiring for this project?
Btw, I have a neighbor across the street who is licensed and does general construction and fine carpentry and another neighbor from a different place who is an architect (not sure if licensed or not). I'm deliberating whether I should hire my neighbor (he just had leg surgery and walking with a cane) across the street to do construction because if the construction turns out bad, I strain the relationship with the neighbor across the street, and also whether I should hire my neighbor from another place who does the design because I kinda don't prefer he knows where I live (just because if the design turns out bad, I strain another relationship with him and exposes my address of where I live).
How should I proceed? Thank you.

You don't need either. Buy a shed or find one of the many companies that come to your place and put one together. It's a shed not a new apartment building.

About the only thing you really need is to check with local building department if you need permits.  Most places do not require permits for small sheds(10x12exp).  A storage building might be big, but most big building stores will have plans/kits you can buy/use.

Don't forget to check your HOA (if you live in one).

Yes, you may have setback and size requirements.

You don't need an architect to build a storage building.
Unless you're talking about a new barn, an architect is way overkill.  Any qualified carpenter can build a simple structure like this, you could do it given enough time and YouTube views, plus a measuring tape, pencil, saw, and a hammer.  All the other tools are just to make it easier.
My recommendation is go to a big box store or the local lot that has a bunch of storage buildings sitting on it and buy one either already made or pre-cut.  Both will have instructions for the foundation appropriate for where you live, or the seller will have contractors available to do it for you.  These buildings are made in a nice dry shop by people who make them by the dozens, which makes them cheaper.  Plus you can stand in it and see that you like it.

Note: before putting your money down, check that your town will let you put the size structure you want in the place you want to put it, and find out if there are special requirements for the type of foundation you put under it. In my neighborhood, we have to be careful not to impede groundwater absorption or flow, which limits both the size permitted and the kinds of footings that are acceptable. To get the one I want, I may have to sacrifice part of my driveway so I have more water absorbing surface to compensate.

Similarly, do double-check that razing one to rebuild it is acceptable. Sometimes local laws have changed, and while existing constructions are grand-fathered (and thus unaffected), new constructions are not, and replacements... may? Definitely worth checking beforehand.

And check what you can put up BEFORE you knock down the old one, as that may affect the answer - you may be able to replace something more substantial than you would be allowed to build from scratch, depending on jurisdiction etc.

@Tiger Guy What if I need the city planning department to approve the plan for my storage building, do I need an architect to draft a blueprint for the city to approve first before the contractor can pull the permit?

@HelloDarkWorld Ask the guy at the lot filled with storage buildings how it works where you live.
